# Kinect + Openni/Freenect + Multiple machines

Tags: ros, ros-master-uri, roscore, freenect-launch, openni.launch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've learned that ROS allows for [talking/subscribing of topics over the network](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines) by utilizing ROS_MASTER_URI. I'm trying to get my Kinect data to work in a similar fashion.

Senario:

- Computer (10.0.0.22) "Master" runs `roscore` and `rviz`
- Computer (10.0.0.4) "Bot" runs `roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch` OR `roslaunch freenect_launch freenect.launch`

Both computers have `export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://10.0.0.22:11311`

So `roscore` is running and `roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch` are both running fine but things get weird with the introduction of `rosrun rviz rviz`. On "Bot" I see the terminal print out the following immediately when `rviz` boots up:

```
$ roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch
... logging to /home/ubuntu/.ros/log/b945d67e-f8fd-11e5-a7b3-0800270c17fb/roslaunch-ubuntu-3091.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://ubuntu:43440/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /camera/camera_nodelet_manager/num_worker_threads: 4
 * /camera/depth_rectify_depth/interpolation: 0
 * /camera/depth_registered_rectify_depth/interpolation: 0
 * /camera/disparity_depth/max_range: 4.0
 * /camera/disparity_depth/min_range: 0.5
 * /camera/disparity_registered_hw/max_range: 4.0
 * /camera/disparity_registered_hw/min_range: 0.5
 * /camera/disparity_registered_sw/max_range: 4.0
 * /camera/disparity_registered_sw/min_range: 0.5
 * /camera/driver/depth_camera_info_url: 
 * /camera/driver/depth_frame_id: camera_depth_opti...
 * /camera/driver/depth_registration: False
 * /camera/driver/device_id: #1
 * /camera/driver/rgb_camera_info_url: 
 * /camera/driver/rgb_frame_id: camera_rgb_optica...
 * /rosdistro: indigo
 * /rosversion: 1.11.16

NODES
  /camera/
    camera_nodelet_manager (nodelet/nodelet)
    debayer (nodelet/nodelet)
    depth_metric (nodelet/nodelet)
    depth_metric_rect (nodelet/nodelet)
    depth_points (nodelet/nodelet)
    depth_rectify_depth (nodelet/nodelet)
    depth_registered_hw_metric_rect (nodelet/nodelet)
    depth_registered_metric (nodelet/nodelet)
    depth_registered_rectify_depth (nodelet/nodelet)
    depth_registered_sw_metric_rect (nodelet/nodelet)
    disparity_depth (nodelet/nodelet)
    disparity_registered_hw (nodelet/nodelet)
    disparity_registered_sw (nodelet/nodelet)
    driver (nodelet/nodelet)
    points_xyzrgb_hw_registered (nodelet/nodelet)
    points_xyzrgb_sw_registered (nodelet/nodelet)
    rectify_color (nodelet/nodelet)
    rectify_ir (nodelet/nodelet)
    rectify_mono (nodelet/nodelet)
    register_depth_rgb (nodelet/nodelet)
  /
    camera_base_link (tf/static_transform_publisher)
    camera_base_link1 (tf/static_transform_publisher)
    camera_base_link2 (tf/static_transform_publisher)
    camera_base_link3 (tf/static_transform_publisher)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://10.0.0.22:11311

core service [/rosout] found
process[camera/camera_nodelet_manager-1]: started with pid [3100]
process[camera/driver-2]: started with pid [3101]
process[camera/debayer-3]: started with pid [3102]
process[camera/rectify_mono-4]: started with pid [3103]
process[camera/rectify_color-5]: started with pid [3107]
process[camera/rectify_ir-6]: started with pid [3112]
process[camera/depth_rectify_depth-7]: started with pid [3113]
process[camera/depth_metric_rect-8]: started with pid [3121]
process[camera/depth_metric-9]: started with pid [3122]
process[camera/depth_points-10]: started with pid [3126]
process[camera/register_depth_rgb-11]: started with pid [3127]
process[camera/points_xyzrgb_sw_registered-12]: started with pid [3128]
process[camera/depth_registered_sw_metric_rect-13]: started with pid [3138]
process[camera/depth_registered_rectify_depth-14]: started with pid [3145]
process[camera/points_xyzrgb_hw_registered-15]: started with pid [3147]
process[camera/depth_registered_hw_metric_rect-16]: started with pid [3155]
process[camera/depth_registered_metric-17]: started with pid [3157]
process[camera/disparity_depth-18]: started with pid [3161]
[ INFO] [1459620448.933287052]: Initializing nodelet with 4 worker threads.
process[camera/disparity_registered_sw-19]: started with pid [3162]
process[camera/disparity_registered_hw-20]: started with pid [3174]
process[camera_base_link-21]: started with pid [3182]
process[camera_base_link1-22]: started with pid [3183]
process[camera_base_link2-23]: started with pid [3184]
process[camera_base_link3-24]: started with pid [3185]
Warning: USB events thread - failed to set priority. This might cause loss of data...
Warning: USB events thread - failed to set priority. This might cause loss of data...
Warning: USB events thread - failed to set priority. This might cause loss of data...
Warning: USB events thread - failed to set priority. This might cause loss of data...
Warning: USB events thread - failed to set priority. This might cause loss of data...
Warning: USB events thread - failed to set priority. This might cause loss of data...
[ INFO] [1459620459.529921904]: Number devices connected: 2
Warning: USB events thread - failed to set priority. This might cause loss of data...
[ INFO] [1459620459.701988258]: 1. device on bus 001:09 is a SensorKinect (2ae) from PrimeSense (45e) with serial id '0'
[ INFO] [1459620459.702705081]: 2. device on bus 001:09 is a SensorV2 (2ae) from PrimeSense (45e) with serial id 'A00365806688049A'
[ INFO] [1459620459.721341696]: Searching for device with index = 1
[FATAL] [1459620461.020970916]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1459620461.021271801]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1459620461.022621593]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1459620461.022621645]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1459620461.023807947]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1459620461.024677791]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1459620461.026253780]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1459620461.026253780]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1459620461.026506905]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1459620461.028658520]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1459620461.028924718]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1459620461.029465030]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1459620461.030274978]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1459620461.031086384]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1459620461.032245707]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1459620461.033092739]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1459620461.034566228]: Service call failed!
[camera/camera_nodelet_manager-1] process has died [pid 3100, exit code -11, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/nodelet/nodelet manager __name:=camera_nodelet_manager __log:=/home/ubuntu/.ros/log/b945d67e-f8fd-11e5-a7b3-0800270c17fb/camera-camera_nodelet_manager-1.log].
log file: /home/ubuntu/.ros/log/b945d67e-f8fd-11e5-a7b3-0800270c17fb/camera-camera_nodelet_manager-1*.log
[camera/depth_points-10] process has died [pid 3126, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/nodelet/nodelet load depth_image_proc/point_cloud_xyz camera_nodelet_manager --no-bond image_rect:=depth/image_rect_raw points:=depth/points __name:=depth_points __log:=/home/ubuntu/.ros/log/b945d67e-f8fd-11e5-a7b3-0800270c17fb/camera-depth_points-10.log].
log file: /home/ubuntu/.ros/log/b945d67e-f8fd-11e5-a7b3-0800270c17fb/camera-depth_points-10*.log
[camera/depth_metric-9] process has died [pid 3122, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/nodelet/nodelet load depth_image_proc/convert_metric camera_nodelet_manager --no-bond image_raw:=depth/image_raw image:=depth/image __name:=depth_metric __log:=/home/ubuntu/.ros/log/b945d67e-f8fd-11e5-a7b3-0800270c17fb/camera-depth_metric-9.log].
log file: /home/ubuntu/.ros/log/b945d67e-f8fd-11e5-a7b3-0800270c17fb/camera-depth_metric-9*.log
[camera/depth_registered_sw_metric_rect-13] process has died [pid 3138, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/nodelet/nodelet load depth_image_proc/convert_metric camera_nodelet_manager --no-bond image_raw:=depth_registered/sw_registered/image_rect_raw image:=depth_registered/sw_registered/image_rect __name:=depth_registered_sw_metric_rect __log:=/home/ubuntu/.ros/log/b945d67e-f8fd-11e5-a7b3-0800270c17fb/camera-depth_registered_sw_metric_rect-13.log].
log file: /home/ubuntu/.ros/log/b945d67e-f8fd-11e5-a7b3-0800270c17fb/camera-depth_registered_sw_metric_rect-13*.log
[camera/depth_registered_rectify_depth-14] process has died [pid 3145, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/nodelet/nodelet load image_proc/rectify camera_nodelet_manager --no-bond image_mono:=depth_registered/image_raw image_rect:=depth_registered/hw_registered/image_rect_raw __name:=depth_registered_rectify_depth __log:=/home/ubuntu/.ros/log/b945d67e-f8fd-11e5-a7b3-0800270c17fb/camera-depth_registered_rectify_depth-14.log].
log file: /home/ubuntu/.ros/log/b945d67e-f8fd-11e5-a7b3-0800270c17fb/camera-depth_registered_rectify_depth-14*.log
[camera/points_xyzrgb_hw_registered-15] process has died [pid 3147, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/nodelet/nodelet load depth_image_proc/point_cloud_xyzrgb camera_nodelet_manager --no-bond rgb/image_rect_color:=rgb/image_rect_color rgb/camera_info:=rgb/camera_info depth_registered/image_rect:=depth_registered/hw_registered/image_rect_raw depth_registered/points:=depth_registered/points __name:=points_xyzrgb_hw_registered __log:=/home/ubuntu/.ros/log/b945d67e-f8fd-11e5-a7b3-0800270c17fb/camera-points_xyzrgb_hw_registered-15.log].
log file: /home/ubuntu/.ros/log/b945d67e-f8fd-11e5-a7b3-0800270c17fb/camera-points_xyzrgb_hw_registered-15*.log
[camera/depth_registered_hw_metric_rect-16] process has died [pid 3155, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/nodelet/nodelet load depth_image_proc/convert_metric camera_nodelet_manager --no-bond image_raw:=depth_registered/hw_registered/image_rect_raw image:=depth_registered/hw_registered/image_rect __name:=depth_registered_hw_metric_rect __log:=/home/ubuntu/.ros/log/b945d67e-f8fd-11e5-a7b3-0800270c17fb/camera-depth_registered_hw_metric_rect-16.log].
log file: /home/ubuntu/.ros/log/b945d67e-f8fd-11e5-a7b3-0800270c17fb/camera-depth_registered_hw_metric_rect-16*.log
[camera/depth_registered_metric-17] process has died [pid 3157, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/nodelet/nodelet load depth_image_proc/convert_metric camera_nodelet_manager --no-bond image_raw:=depth_registered/image_raw image:=depth_registered/image __name:=depth_registered_metric __log:=/home/ubuntu/.ros/log/b945d67e-f8fd-11e5-a7b3-0800270c17fb/camera-depth_registered_metric-17.log].
log file: /home/ubuntu/.ros/log/b945d67e-f8fd-11e5-a7b3-0800270c17fb/camera-depth_registered_metric-17*.log
[camera/disparity_registered_hw-20] process has died [pid 3174, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/nodelet/nodelet load depth_image_proc/disparity camera_nodelet_manager --no-bond left/image_rect:=depth_registered/hw_registered/image_rect_raw right:=projector left/disparity:=depth_registered/disparity __name:=disparity_registered_hw __log:=/home/ubuntu/.ros/log/b945d67e-f8fd-11e5-a7b3-0800270c17fb/camera-disparity_registered_hw-20.log].
log file: /home/ubuntu/.ros/log/b945d67e-f8fd-11e5-a7b3-0800270c17fb/camera-disparity_registered_hw-20*.log
[camera/driver-2] process has died [pid 3101, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/nodelet/nodelet load openni_camera/driver camera_nodelet_manager --no-bond ir:=ir rgb:=rgb depth:=depth depth_registered:=depth_registered projector:=projector __name:=driver __log:=/home/ubuntu/.ros/log/b945d67e-f8fd-11e5-a7b3-0800270c17fb/camera-driver-2.log].
log file: /home/ubuntu/.ros/log/b945d67e-f8fd-11e5-a7b3-0800270c17fb/camera-driver-2*.log
[camera/rectify_color-5] process has died [pid 3107, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/nodelet/nodelet load image_proc/rectify camera_nodelet_manager --no-bond image_mono:=rgb/image_color image_rect:=rgb/image_rect_color __name:=rectify_color __log:=/home/ubuntu/.ros/log/b945d67e-f8fd-11e5-a7b3-0800270c17fb/camera-rectify_color-5.log].
log file: /home/ubuntu/.ros/log/b945d67e-f8fd-11e5-a7b3-0800270c17fb/camera-rectify_color-5*.log
[camera/rectify_ir-6] process has died [pid 3112, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/nodelet/nodelet load image_proc/rectify camera_nodelet_manager --no-bond image_mono:=ir/image_raw image_rect:=ir/image_rect_ir __name:=rectify_ir __log:=/home/ubuntu/.ros/log/b945d67e-f8fd-11e5-a7b3-0800270c17fb/camera-rectify_ir-6.log].
log file: /home/ubuntu/.ros/log/b945d67e-f8fd-11e5-a7b3-0800270c17fb/camera-rectify_ir-6*.log
[camera/depth_rectify_depth-7] process has died [pid 3113, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/nodelet/nodelet load image_proc/rectify camera_nodelet_manager --no-bond image_mono:=depth/image_raw image_rect:=depth/image_rect_raw __name:=depth_rectify_depth __log:=/home/ubuntu/.ros/log/b945d67e-f8fd-11e5-a7b3-0800270c17fb/camera-depth_rectify_depth-7.log].
log file: /home/ubuntu/.ros/log/b945d67e-f8fd-11e5-a7b3-0800270c17fb/camera-depth_rectify_depth-7*.log
[camera/depth_metric_rect-8] process has died [pid 3121, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/nodelet/nodelet load depth_image_proc/convert_metric camera_nodelet_manager --no-bond image_raw:=depth/image_rect_raw image:=depth/image_rect __name:=depth_metric_rect __log:=/home/ubuntu/.ros/log/b945d67e-f8fd-11e5-a7b3-0800270c17fb/camera-depth_metric_rect-8.log].
log file: /home/ubuntu/.ros/log/b945d67e-f8fd-11e5-a7b3-0800270c17fb/camera-depth_metric_rect-8*.log
[camera/points_xyzrgb_sw_registered-12] process has died [pid 3128, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/nodelet/nodelet load depth_image_proc/point_cloud_xyzrgb camera_nodelet_manager --no-bond rgb/image_rect_color:=rgb/image_rect_color rgb/camera_info:=rgb/camera_info depth_registered/image_rect:=depth_registered/sw_registered/image_rect_raw depth_registered/points:=depth_registered/points __name:=points_xyzrgb_sw_registered __log:=/home/ubuntu/.ros/log/b945d67e-f8fd-11e5-a7b3-0800270c17fb/camera-points_xyzrgb_sw_registered-12.log].
log file: /home/ubuntu/.ros/log/b945d67e-f8fd-11e5-a7b3-0800270c17fb/camera-points_xyzrgb_sw_registered-12*.log
[camera/disparity_depth-18] process has died [pid 3161, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/nodelet/nodelet load depth_image_proc/disparity camera_nodelet_manager --no-bond left/image_rect:=depth/image_rect_raw right:=projector left/disparity:=depth/disparity __name:=disparity_depth __log:=/home/ubuntu/.ros/log/b945d67e-f8fd-11e5-a7b3-0800270c17fb/camera-disparity_depth-18.log].
log file: /home/ubuntu/.ros/log/b945d67e-f8fd-11e5-a7b3-0800270c17fb/camera-disparity_depth-18*.log
[camera/register_depth_rgb-11] process has died [pid 3127, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/nodelet/nodelet load depth_image_proc/register camera_nodelet_manager --no-bond rgb/camera_info:=rgb/camera_info depth/camera_info:=depth/camera_info depth/image_rect:=depth/image_rect_raw depth_registered/image_rect:=depth_registered/sw_registered/image_rect_raw __name:=register_depth_rgb __log:=/home/ubuntu/.ros/log/b945d67e-f8fd-11e5-a7b3-0800270c17fb/camera-register_depth_rgb-11.log].
log file: /home/ubuntu/.ros/log/b945d67e-f8fd-11e5-a7b3-0800270c17fb/camera-register_depth_rgb-11*.log
[camera/disparity_registered_sw-19] process has died [pid 3162, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/nodelet/nodelet load depth_image_proc/disparity camera_nodelet_manager --no-bond left/image_rect:=depth_registered/sw_registered/image_rect_raw right:=projector left/disparity:=depth_registered/disparity __name:=disparity_registered_sw __log:=/home/ubuntu/.ros/log/b945d67e-f8fd-11e5-a7b3-0800270c17fb/camera-disparity_registered_sw-19.log].
log file: /home/ubuntu/.ros/log/b945d67e-f8fd-11e5-a7b3-0800270c17fb/camera-disparity_registered_sw-19*.log
```

With `roslaunch freenect_launch freenect.launch` things seem better but shortly after it starts (and the Kinect's laser projector turns on) It shuts off with terminal output of `[ INFO] [1459620527.170462997]: Stopping device RGB and Depth stream flush.`

```
$ roslaunch freenect_launch freenect.launch
... logging to /home/ubuntu/.ros/log/b945d67e-f8fd-11e5-a7b3-0800270c17fb/roslaunch-ubuntu-3254.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://ubuntu:37085/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /camera/camera_nodelet_manager/num_worker_threads: 4
 * /camera/depth_rectify_depth/interpolation: 0
 * /camera/depth_registered_rectify_depth/interpolation: 0
 * /camera/disparity_depth/max_range: 4.0
 * /camera/disparity_depth/min_range: 0.5
 * /camera/disparity_registered_hw/max_range: 4.0
 * /camera/disparity_registered_hw/min_range: 0.5
 * /camera/disparity_registered_sw/max_range: 4.0
 * /camera/disparity_registered_sw/min_range: 0.5
 * /camera/driver/data_skip: 0
 * /camera/driver/debug: False
 * /camera/driver/depth_camera_info_url: 
 * /camera/driver/depth_frame_id: camera_depth_opti...
 * /camera/driver/depth_registration: False
 * /camera/driver/device_id: #1
 * /camera/driver/diagnostics_max_frequency: 30.0
 * /camera/driver/diagnostics_min_frequency: 30.0
 * /camera/driver/diagnostics_tolerance: 0.05
 * /camera/driver/diagnostics_window_time: 5.0
 * /camera/driver/enable_depth_diagnostics: False
 * /camera/driver/enable_ir_diagnostics: False
 * /camera/driver/enable_rgb_diagnostics: False
 * /camera/driver/rgb_camera_info_url: 
 * /camera/driver/rgb_frame_id: camera_rgb_optica...
 * /rosdistro: indigo
 * /rosversion: 1.11.16

NODES
  /camera/
    camera_nodelet_manager (nodelet/nodelet)
    debayer (nodelet/nodelet)
    depth_metric (nodelet/nodelet)
    depth_metric_rect (nodelet/nodelet)
    depth_points (nodelet/nodelet)
    depth_rectify_depth (nodelet/nodelet)
    depth_registered_hw_metric_rect (nodelet/nodelet)
    depth_registered_metric (nodelet/nodelet)
    depth_registered_rectify_depth (nodelet/nodelet)
    depth_registered_sw_metric_rect (nodelet/nodelet)
    disparity_depth (nodelet/nodelet)
    disparity_registered_hw (nodelet/nodelet)
    disparity_registered_sw (nodelet/nodelet)
    driver (nodelet/nodelet)
    points_xyzrgb_hw_registered (nodelet/nodelet)
    points_xyzrgb_sw_registered (nodelet/nodelet)
    rectify_color (nodelet/nodelet)
    rectify_ir (nodelet/nodelet)
    rectify_mono (nodelet/nodelet)
    register_depth_rgb (nodelet/nodelet)
  /
    camera_base_link (tf/static_transform_publisher)
    camera_base_link1 (tf/static_transform_publisher)
    camera_base_link2 (tf/static_transform_publisher)
    camera_base_link3 (tf/static_transform_publisher)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://10.0.0.22:11311

core service [/rosout] found
process[camera/camera_nodelet_manager-1]: started with pid [3263]
process[camera/driver-2]: started with pid [3264]
process[camera/debayer-3]: started with pid [3265]
process[camera/rectify_mono-4]: started with pid [3266]
process[camera/rectify_color-5]: started with pid [3270]
process[camera/rectify_ir-6]: started with pid [3272]
process[camera/depth_rectify_depth-7]: started with pid [3282]
process[camera/depth_metric_rect-8]: started with pid [3283]
process[camera/depth_metric-9]: started with pid [3288]
process[camera/depth_points-10]: started with pid [3293]
process[camera/register_depth_rgb-11]: started with pid [3298]
process[camera/points_xyzrgb_sw_registered-12]: started with pid [3299]
process[camera/depth_registered_sw_metric_rect-13]: started with pid [3303]
[ INFO] [1459620521.731632004]: Initializing nodelet with 4 worker threads.
process[camera/depth_registered_rectify_depth-14]: started with pid [3309]
process[camera/points_xyzrgb_hw_registered-15]: started with pid [3313]
process[camera/depth_registered_hw_metric_rect-16]: started with pid [3318]
process[camera/depth_registered_metric-17]: started with pid [3326]
process[camera/disparity_depth-18]: started with pid [3330]
process[camera/disparity_registered_sw-19]: started with pid [3331]
process[camera/disparity_registered_hw-20]: started with pid [3335]
process[camera_base_link-21]: started with pid [3336]
process[camera_base_link1-22]: started with pid [3341]
process[camera_base_link2-23]: started with pid [3342]
process[camera_base_link3-24]: started with pid [3343]
[ INFO] [1459620523.932327943]: Number devices connected: 1
[ INFO] [1459620523.933402839]: 1. device on bus 000:00 is a Xbox NUI Camera (2ae) from Microsoft (45e) with serial id 'A00365806688049A'
[ INFO] [1459620523.954331484]: Searching for device with index = 1
[ INFO] [1459620524.168844141]: Starting a 3s RGB and Depth stream flush.
[ INFO] [1459620524.169588412]: Opened 'Xbox NUI Camera' on bus 0:0 with serial number 'A00365806688049A'
[ INFO] [1459620525.224897840]: rgb_frame_id = 'camera_rgb_optical_frame' 
[ INFO] [1459620525.225280027]: depth_frame_id = 'camera_depth_optical_frame' 
[ WARN] [1459620525.505361798]: Camera calibration file /home/ubuntu/.ros/camera_info/rgb_A00365806688049A.yaml not found.
[ WARN] [1459620525.505736642]: Using default parameters for RGB camera calibration.
[ WARN] [1459620525.506143569]: Camera calibration file /home/ubuntu/.ros/camera_info/depth_A00365806688049A.yaml not found.
[ WARN] [1459620525.506394975]: Using default parameters for IR camera calibration.
[ INFO] [1459620527.170462997]: Stopping device RGB and Depth stream flush.
```

Am I doing something wrong? How can I make sure my topic is being published and is reachable over the network?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/230795/kinect-+-openni/freenect-+-multiple-machines/) by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) on ROS Answers with karma: 396 on 2016-04-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

** **EDIT** **

I didn't have all my facts and figures straight before writing this answer. The fact is that it doesn't matter where the master is or where the camera is. Once your settings correspond correctly then everything should work. Make sure the following two items are addressed on ALL machines.

- `ROS_MASTER_URI` - *IP of the machine to act as the "server", needs be the same on all machines*
- `ROS_IP` - *the IP of the current machine, needs to be different on all machines*

**--- Original Answer Below ---**

I had the right idea and found out where I was wrong. The "master" is really the robot, which seems a little backward to me but now that I know that `roscore` needs to run on the robot I'm set straight. Here's the article that put me on the right track:

[Getting RVIZ to Work Over Multiple Computers](http://www.umiacs.umd.edu/%7Ecteo/umd-erratic-ros-data/README-rvis-remote)

And in case the link ever dies, here's the content of the link since it's short:

> ### README on getting RVIS to work over
> multiple computers
>
> A common task is to SSH into the
> robot's computer and run RVIZ to get
> the laser output and other
> visualization. Running RVIZ directly
> on the remote computer will not work
> due to the way RVIZ is implemented.
> The workaround is to run RVIZ locally.
> To do this we need to set the local
> computer to locate the remote MASTER
> NODE in order to display the right
> information.
>
> Assume: IP: 192.168.1.0 // remote
> computer (robot) IP: 192.168.1.1 //
> local computer (host)
>
> *** ssh into remote computer ***
>
> 1. ssh -X erratic@192.168.1.0
>
> At the remote terminal:
> 2. export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.1.0:11311
> //this ensures that we do not use
> localhost, but the real IP address as
> master node
>
> 3. export ROS_IP=192.168.1.0      //this ensures that ROS knows that we cannot
>    use hostname directly (due to DHCP
>    firewall issues)
> 4. roscore
>
> At the local terminal:
>
> 1. export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.1.0:11311
>    //tells local computer to look for the
>    remote here
> 2. export ROS_IP=192.168.1.1      //this ensures that ROS knows that we cannot
>    use hostname directly (due to DHCP
>    firewall issues)
> 3. rosrun rviz rviz           // fires up rviz on local computer. It will attach
>    to the master node of the remote
>    computer
>
> ** to check, open a remote terminal **
>
> 1. rxgraph
>
> ** Note, everytime a new terminal is open on the local/remote computer, we
> have to call the 2 exports commands.
> To make this permanent, edit the
> ~/.bashrc file:
>
> 1. sudo gedit ~/.bashrc //add the two export commands at the end of the
>    file.
> 2. source ~/.bashrc //and restart terminal

---

Originally posted by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) with karma: 396 on 2016-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0